# Install ANARCI on RHEL 6

Tags: rhel, python

I want to install [ANARCI](http://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/ANARCI.php) on RHEL 6. I have Python 2.7.7 installed. As you can read their home page, ANARCI requires Python 2.6+ and HMMER3. 
I downloaded anarci tar.gz then unpacked it. 
Installed it with

```
python setup.py install --prefix=/tmp/anarci
```

But when I run `/tmp/anarci/bin/ANARCI -h`, it shows no module named ANARCI.

How do I specify the HMMER dependency in this case. How can I install ANARCI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. Your suggestions worked for me , only thing I changed that after python , I have to append site-packages to PYTHONPATH.

So export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/anarci/lib/python/site-packages/:$PYTHONPATH did the job.

On Mon, May 29, 2017 at 6:53 PM, Dunbar, James  wrote:
Hi Prashant,

Apologies for the slow reply.

The anarci python module needs to be in your PYTHONPATH env variable and hmmscan binary (from hmmer3) in your PATH.

e.g. with a bash shell first run:

export PYTHONPATH=/tmp/anarci/lib/python/:$PYTHONPATH
export PATH=/tmp/HMMER-3.1/binaries/:$PATH

then:
/tmp/anarci/bin/ANARCI

Hope that helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.

Best, 
James

On 29 May 2017 at 15:13, James Dunbar  wrote:

---------- Forwarded message ----------
From: Prashant Shete <​​prince.shete@gmail.com>
Date: 22 May 2017 at 20:18
Subject: Antibody Numbering - ANARCI Install
To: dunbar@stats.ox.ac.uk

Hi James,

I tried to install ANARCI from http://opig.stats.ox.ac.uk/webapps/sabdab-sabpred/ANARCI.php

As it says , it requires python 2.6+ and HMMER3. I downloaded anarci tar.gz , unpacked it and ran python setup.py install --prefix=/tmp/anarci on RHEL 6 machine.

I also downloaded HMMER-3.1 , done make, make install with prefix /tmp/HMMER-3.1.

But when I run /tmp/anarci/bin/ANARCI it shows no module named  anarci. Is it because I haven't specified HMMER dependancy, if so how can I do that.